# blank iis8 localhost page on windows 8 laptop

Tags: windows-8, iis-8

Good day,

I'm trying to install IIS on windows 8 laptop.
When i type [http://localhost] it gives me a blank page. 
I can ping localhost and 127.0.0.1 and get replies and gmail developer tools give me a status of 200 OK. 
I have McAfee total protection installed and i disabled the firewall on it. I also disabled windows firewall.
i just uninstalled Skype.
I completely bypassed my router and connected straight from the modem.
I restarted and nothing . Just want to get the default iis page up and running
Nothing is working please assist.

Comment: This seemed to have done the trick for me.Somehow http redirects was not installed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173698/why-are-blank-pages-being-served-with-200-ok-for-asp-net-errors-in-iis-8-5-wi

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case HTTP Redirects doesn't work, check to see that Static Content is enabled as well.

Both of these were not enabled on my new Windows 8.1 > IIS 8.5 ...

Both can be enabled here:

Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features On/Off > IIS > WWW Services > Common HTTP Features

I enabled HTTP Redirects, still blank. Then I enabled Static Content and halleluah !

http://forums.iis.net/p/1152570/1882738.aspx